# trying to install ubuntu touch to nexus 4 - can't connect device (14.04 in virtual box on mac)

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I'm trying to install Ubuntu touch to a nexus 4.

I've followed all the steps so far, downloaded the packages and gotten the phone ready, but now I got to the step of connecting it to the computer [under 'Enable USB Debugging'], but it's not listed when I try $ adb devices  (I tried the 'adb kill-server' command first too, but nothing is listed).

I'm sure it's something simple I'm forgetting, but can anyone help please?   I have debugging enabled.  Running Trusty in VirtualBox on MacBook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - sorted it out!  I clicked the USB icon in bottom right of VirtualBox and selected the Nexus.  (leaving question up in case it's of use to someone else)